# What do these U.S. states have in common?

Tags: knowledge

The following U.S. states have something in common that is not shared by any other state:

- Alabama
- Arkansas
- California
- Colorado
- Florida
- Georgia
- Indiana
- Louisiana
- Maryland
- Minnesota
- Missouri
- Montana
- Nebraska
- New Hampshire
- North Dakota
- Pennsylvania
- South Carolina

What is it?

Comment: there in a list on some seemingly random question posted on a puzzling site...

Comment: No one from there has ever been to Cliff Clavin's house?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These states ...

> ... have postal abbreviations that are symbols of chemical elements:
>
> ```
>                                Alabama AL   Al Aluminium
>                               Arkansas AR   Ar Argon
>                             California CA   Ca Calcium
>                               Colorado CO   Co Cobalt
>                                Florida FL   Fl Flerovium
>                                Georgia GA   Ga Gallium
>                                Indiana IN   In Indium
>                              Louisiana LA   La Lanthanum
>                               Maryland MD   Md Mendelevium
>                              Minnesota MN   Mn Manganese
>                               Missouri MO   Mo Molybdenium
>                                Montana MT   Mt Meitnerium
>                               Nebraska NE   Ne Neon
>                          New Hampshire NH   Nh Nihonium
>                           North Dakota ND   Nd Neodymium
>                           Pennsylvania PA   Pa Protactinum
>                         South Carolina SC   Sc Scandium
> ```

Comment: That's quite a research effort! Great!!

Comment: Well, I first thought they were the states with or without a town called [Springfield](http://springfield.ftldesign.com/). But that was wrong, so it had to be something else.